# Error message when launching android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

I tried launch my app in React Native with `npx react-native run-android` on terminal and this error happen

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.    
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warning 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M        

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.        
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\AppDentista\android\app\build.gradle' line: 87

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script 'C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\AppDentista\node_modules\expo-updates\scripts\create-manifest-android.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. 
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

I wanna start and install my application on Android emulator, but this error always happen when I try. This says something is missing, but I don't know what. I didn't find the same problem as mine elsewhere on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got, if you have the same problem. Do you need install all dependencies again (Android Studio, React and Java). After that, create a project with `npx react-native init Project`, and finish!